# C# check if records already exist

Tags: c#

Hi i'm very new to programming and I want to ask about my code here, In Lab inventory with borrowing and returning transaction, I want to stop a borrower from borrowing the same item if he hasn't return it yet but i'm getting an error You have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual that corresponds to you MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ItemId='2' AND BorrowerId='2' this is my code:

```
conn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM transactions_table WHERE ReturnDate IS NULL, ItemId=@ItemId AND BorrowerId=@BorrowerId";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BorrowerId", txtBorrowStudentId.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemId", txtBorrowItemId.Text);
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate present");
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear: "You have an error in your SQL syntax check.... near 'ItemId='2' AND BorrowerId='2' ". add "NULL **AND** ItemId=@ItemId" and it will work.

Comment: Btw: It is always a good idea to test manual created queries by an external db tool. I don't know MariaDB and could not tell you, how it is named there but I am shure, something like this exists.

Comment: Yet another suggestion: You do not need to read the datarow. Change your query to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM....` and Use `if(((int)cmd.ExecuteScaler()) > 0) ` to check whether there are record matching your condition or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mistake is `ReturnDate IS NULL,`

```
SELECT * FROM transactions_table WHERE ReturnDate IS NULL and ItemId=@ItemId AND BorrowerId=@BorrowerId
```